# How to invoke function inside another function in JavaScript as I've mentioned below

Tags: javascript

I've a code

```
function person() {
   name =  "David";
   hello =  function() {
      console.log("I'm in hello");
   };
}
```

And I want to invoke hello function from outside. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should be initializing your variables with "var" otherwise you're creating global variables.

Comment: @tfmontague So here name and hello are global isn't it? so why can't I invoke hello() simply?I'm totally confused. help me

Comment: you will not be able to invoke hello() untill you invoke person()....as on calling person()...hello would be actually declared and then it will be available for further global calls.

Comment: @Vijay But I'm able invoke name as console.log(name) from outside. But why can't I do this with hello()?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is for your curiosity and clarity :)

You have declared global variables inside a function. Untill you execute the function the global variables will not come into existence and would not be accessible. Once you call the function the globals would be defined and initialized properly and thereafter you can call them from any scope in the javascript.

```
function person() {
   name =  "David";
   hello =  function() {
      console.log("I'm in hello");
   };
}
```

Now, in order to call hello from outside **without using this or class pattern**, you will have to first make a call (method execution) to `person` method. see this:

either `person();` or `console.log(person());` but not `console.log(person);`
and then you can easily call `hello();`

> NOTE: This is for David's understanding purpose. Please do not use
>   arbitrarily  global variables in your javascript.

Comment: @David: You _are_ aware that you're just creating a global variable then, right?

Comment: @Cerbrus: this solution is just to make david understand why his code was not working. As a developer I would not recommend global variables in javascript.

Comment: @Vijay: This solution __only__ explains what the OP has to do to make it "work". It doesn't warn about globals, it doesn't even _mention_  globals. This answer does not promote any sort of understanding. It's just a "easy workaround".

Comment: @Cerbrus: Thanks, I have added a global warning :)

Comment: It still doesn't explain anything. Sure, it "works", but you're not explaining why it works.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Please let me know if this explains?

Comment: The answer is still promoting the usage of globals, then suggesting not to use globals...

Answer (score 3):

Assign `hello` (and `name`) to `this` in `person`:

```
function Person() {
   this.name = "David";
   this.hello = function() {
      console.log("I'm in hello");
   };
};
```

Then, you can access the function like this:

```
var p = new Person();
p.hello();
```

`this` assigns the variables to the `Person`. This prevents the variables from polluting the global scope.

You could also pass parameters to `Person`:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.hello = function() {
    alert("Hello! I'm " + this.name + '!');
  };
};

var p = new Person("Fred");
p.hello();
```

Comment: Without using this can't I invoke?

Comment: @David `this` in JavaScript is _explicit_ in objects (like Python, and unlike Java and C#). You _have_ to use `this` whenever you want to refer to the context (except in edge cases).

Answer (score 2):

```
function person() {
   this.name =  "David";
   this.hello =  function() {
      console.log("I'm in hello");
   };
}
var personObj = new person();
personObj.hello ();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is that:

```
function person() {
   name =  "David";
   this.hello =  function() {
      console.log("I'm in hello");
   };
}
var johnny = new person();
johnny.hello();
```

See this nice article: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 0):

```
function person() {
   name =  "David";
   this.hello =  function() {
      console.log("I'm in hello");
   };
}

var p = new person();
p.hello();
```

or

```
  function person() {
       var obj={}; 
       obj.name =  "David";
       obj.hello =  function() {
          console.log("I'm in hello");
       };
       return obj;
    }

    var p = person();
    p.hello();
```